# automatically resizing excel columns with PHP

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have seen this question in many places, yet, the most common answer does not work for me, for some reason.

I have a somewhat simple code that exports data from an Array, to Excel. It looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
    set_time_limit(600);        
    $ArrSer = json_decode($_POST['excel_array']);
    $objPHPExcel = new phpExcel();

    // Auto Resize Columns
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getColumnDimension('E')
            ->setAutoSize(true);

    // Header
    $header = $_SESSION['excel_array']['strategy']['Plan1'][0]; 


(new Export(Export::EXCEL))
    ->addSheet(
        "Plan1",
        array_merge(
        $ArrSer
        )
    )
    ->download($_SESSION['excel_name']['strategy']);
```

So as you can see, im trying to set AutoSize on the 'E' column. That is mostly for testing, and after i achieve that i'll try to loop it through the other columns.

So this code is what i found around the internet in order to resize the columns, yet it doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: Where does `(new Export(Export::EXCEL))` come from? Is this some kind of wrapper library? Is it something provided by your framework?

Comment: It comes from a .premise file that calls the library. I'm not 100% sure, since i am not the one who made it, but i think that's it.

Comment: Well if `(new Export(Export::EXCEL))` is using PHPExcel (and I have no way of knowing whether it is or not) then something like `(new Export(Export::EXCEL))
    ->addSheet(
        "Plan1",
        array_merge(
        $ArrSer
        )
    )->getColumnDimension('E')
            ->setAutoSize(true)
    ->download($_SESSION['excel_name']['strategy']);` might work, but it's difficult to say without knowing anything about that `Export` class

Comment: I believe it does use PHPExcel, from what my boss told me. But using this code you just provided i get an Fatal error saying
"Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! ". What does that mean?

Comment: I haven't a clue what it means, because I have no idea what's in the `Export` class.... that's not part of PHPExcel, and I can only make some basic guesses about how it works with PHPExcel